# Parametric minimization running forever

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I am trying to solve for the minimum distance between a line and a cone, for all possible lines in 3D space. I've formulated this as a call to `Minimize`, but it seems to run forever. (I aborted execution after 16 hours.)

```
MyLine[t_] := {p1, p2, p3} + t*{v1, v2, v2}
MyNorm2[v_] := Dot[v, v]
Minimize[{MyNorm2[{x, y, z} - MyLine[t]], x^2 + y^2 <= z^2, 0 <= z <= 1}, {x, y, z, t}]
```

I don't expect there to be many cases in this small problem, so I am surprised that it is taking as long as it does. Is there some way I can debug what is going on? From looking at the tutorial on [constrained optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationExact.html), it seems that Mathematica is capable of solving what appears to be more complicated instances than what I am trying now.

Comment: I am not trying to do numerical minimization. I am trying to explicitly find the solution for values of p and v.

Comment: At least, replace `ˆ` with `^`.

Comment: Condition for the cone should be  `x^2 + y^2 <= z` not `x^2 + y^2 <= z^2` !?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I want a "linear" cone, so norm([x,y]) <= z, or norm([x,y])^2 <= z^2,

Comment: @Gus I agree, that's why the condition must be `x^2 + y^2=Norm[{x,y}] <= z`

Comment: Is that what `Norm` means in Mathematica? It's not the traditional definition, which looks like the Pythagorean theorem. For example, it doesn't obey the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Gus It is the usual definition `x^2 + y^2=Norm[{x,y}]^2 <= z`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You have written both `x^2 + y^2=Norm[{x,y}] ` and `x^2 + y^2=Norm[{x,y}]^2` in your comments. and you have also written both `Norm[{x,y}] <= z` and `Norm[{x,y}]^2 <= z`.

For the record, I want `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)=Norm[{x,y}] <= z`, or equivalently `x^2 + y^2=Norm[{x,y}]^2 <= z^2`

Comment: Maybe you can try: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1402471?p_p_auth=UQ7qfcpM